# Problems with accessing applications under /var/www

Tags: permissions, apache2

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed.

The DocumentRoot is `/var/www/html`

When I type in my url address, it works fine: My test file shows up. When I try an application I installed under `/app1` and `/app2`, they both work fine as well. (`/var/www/app1`, and `/var/www/app2`). Specifically, in my browser, I can go to my `<ip address>/app1`, and the application works, the same with `<ip address>/app2`.

Now, I installed another app under `/app3` (`/var/www/app3`) and when I try to access it in my browser, it keeps saying:
The requested url `/app3` cannot be found.

I compared permissions and ownerships to my other apps and even deleted the app3 files and just put in my own index.html file and it still says cannot be found.

However, when I change the `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/app3`, the app works fine. `/app3` is DokuWiki, btw. I've posted there, but, no one responded. And I don't want it to be my document root.

Why is that? How can my other apps (app1 and app2) work fine and app3 cannot be found?

This is what the structure looks like in `/var/www`:

```
drwxr-x--x 10 root     www-data 4096 May 23 07:40 app1  
drwxrwxr-x  7 root     root     4096 Mar 19 15:29 app3  
drwxrwx--x  2 root     www-data 4096 May 21 16:45 html  
drwxr-x--- 13 root     www-data 4096 May 17 10:00 app2  
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     www-data 4096 May 23 07:47 test
```

So, again, `/app1` and `/app2` works in my browser. `/app3` and `/test` says it cannot be found.

Inside `/test` it looks like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root    108 May 23 07:47 index.html  

$ ls -l app3
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar 19 15:29 bin
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar 19 15:29 conf
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root 18092 Mar 19 15:29 COPYING
drwxrwxr-x 12 root root  4096 Mar 19 15:29 data
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root   182 Mar 19 15:29 index.php
...
```

I have tried the group all www-data before as well.
Inside the directories that work

```
$ ls -l app1
drwx------ 22 root www-data   4096 May 20 17:11 addons
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     639533 May 23 07:40 app.html
drwx------  6 root www-data   4096 May 20 17:11 css
drwx------  4 root www-data   4096 May 20 17:12 images
...
```

This works if I directly access `app.html` in my browser.

```
$ ls -l app2
drwxr-x--- 21 root     www-data  4096 May 17 09:59 3rdparty  
drwxr-x--- 21 www-data www-data  4096 May 17 09:59 apps  
drwxr-x---  2 root     www-data  4096 May  6 14:34 assets  
-rw-r-----  1 root     www-data   477 Apr 23 15:57 AUTHORS  
drwxr-x---  2 www-data www-data  4096 May 17 10:12 config  
-rw-r-----  1 root     www-data  1941 Apr 23 15:57 console.php  
-rw-r-----  1 root     www-data 34520 Apr 23 15:57 COPYING-AGPL  
drwxr-x--- 19 root     www-data  4096 May 17 10:00 core  
-rw-r-----  1 root     www-data  4170 Apr 23 15:57 cron.php  
drwxr-x---  4 www-data www-data  4096 May 17 21:21 data  
-rw-r-----  1 root     www-data 23751 Apr 23 15:57 db_structure.xml  
-rw-r-----  1 root     www-data   179 Apr 23 15:57 index.html  
-rw-r-----  1 root     www-data  1792 Apr 23 15:57 index.php  
...
```

`index.html` just redirects to `index.php`

```
$ ls -l html
-rw-rw---- 1 root www-data   119 May 21 13:00 index.html
```

This is the result of the `grep -R app /etc/apache2/{sites,conf}-enabled` command:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:        #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:        #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:        #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:        #    this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/localized-error-pages.conf:# includes to substitute the appropriate text.
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/localized-error-pages.conf:# You can modify the messages' appearance without changing any of the
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf:# This currently breaks the configurations that come with some web application
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:      AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: Hello linstar. Do you mind placing your current files/folders permissions in the body of your question in order to see what you say? If everything seems to be OK with permissions I would go for APP configuration. The config file of your APP may be pointing to a different place where it is not finding what it expects. Which APP is that you are naming "app3" in this question? Please provide this information in order to get a better support. Good luck!

Comment: What does the `html` directory contain? Also post the output of `grep -R app /etc/apache2/{sites,conf}-enabled`.

Comment: Please use proper formatting. Not HTML br tags. You just undid the decent formatting I had put in.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the note about the formatting on the side.

Comment: Huh. Based on your configuration, there's no reason for `/app1` or `/app2` to work. O.o

Comment: Are /app1 and /app2 supposed to be under /var/www/html (i.e. the directory specified in the DocumentRoot)?

Comment: /app3 is actually DokuWiki. I've posted there, but, no response. And as I mentioned, it works fine if I set it in the DocumentRoot, but, when I change it back to /var/www/html and then access DokuWiki directly with the browser (restarting apache2 first), it doesn't find the directory anymore. I would put <ip address>/app3 for direct access. And when it's set in the DocumentRoot, I just point to my ip address and it works.

Comment: Yes, `app1` and `app2` should have been under `html`. But failing that, you can try one of two things: Create a link from `app3` to `html`: `sudo ln -s /var/www/app3 /var/www/html`, or add an `Alias` to the defaut VirtualHost: `Alias /app3 /var/www/app3`

Comment: So, does this seem like security flaw in the application or apache2?

Answer (score 1):

All my apps had to be put in the DocumentRoot and then they all worked.

What threw me off was the fact that 2 applications that were not in the DocumentRoot still worked and were accessible via my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your permissions may be stuffed. I suggest to do this

```
chown -R root:www-data app3 test
```

This will change the owner and group of all files and folders in app3 and test to owner = root and group = www-data.

Hope that fixes it for you.

Comment: Well, app3 is DokuWiki and it does work if it's set as the DocumentRoot. I tried changing the ownership and groups as you mentioned, but, it didn't make a difference. It still works if I change it to DocumentRoot. No effect on my test directory. Still can't access it.

Comment: which error are you getting? 404 etc? do you have index.php set as a default document?
Have you restarted the server since putting the new apps in there?

Comment: Yes, it's 404 error: The requested URL /app3 was not found on this server. And yes, I restart apache.

Comment: maybe something in your .htaccess
have you checked your log to see if there is anything else in there?